# Breadcrumbs not displaying in Avada as expected with custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress

I've created a custom post type that doesn't display in Avada's breadcrumbs properly. I'm not sure if it's an issue with Avada, or with my implementation of the custom post type.  The URL rewriting is working as expected, it's just the breadcrumbs that are giving me a problem.  Here's a snippet of my code including the taxonomy.

```
function people_init() {
    $args = array(
        'label' => 'People',
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'menu_position' => 20,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'about/people','with_front' => true),
        'has_archive' => false,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-admin-users',
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'revisions',
            'thumbnail',
            'page-attributes',)
    );
    register_post_type( 'tickleme_people', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'people_init' );

function people_taxonomy() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'tickleme_people_tax',
        'tickleme_people',
        array(
            'label' => 'People',
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'show_in_rest' => true,
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'about/people',
                'with_front' => true,
                'hierarchical' => true,
            )
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'people_taxonomy');
```

Comment: Which template is being used for this custom post type? How are the breadcrumbs being generated?

Comment: The breadcrumbs are generated in the Avada theme.  I'm using a child theme.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the theme but I'd guess you'd need to hook into the function that the theme provides for breadcrumbs, and display it in the Custom Field post Template. I'd try to create a new template for your custom post type using the WP hierarchy and add the theme breadcrumb hook manually, either directly in the new CPT template or hook into it in `functions.php`: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/custom-post-type-template-files/#custom-post-type-template-hierarchy